# Чтение данных, записанных через пробелы из файла в C++

Tags: python, c++, файлы, list

Есть простейшая задача - дан массив оценок, из которого нужно удалить двойки, удвоить пятёрки и сортировать оценки по возрастанию. Задача решена на языке Python. Теперь требуется то же самое решить на C++. Сложность вызывает необходимость считывания данных из файла, записанных в строчку через пробел. Как ни пытался искать в интернете, не получается реализовать подобное считывание, не понимаю описанный код, так как опыта в C++ почти нет. Как это сделать, не указывая длину считываемой строки, а оставив её определение программе?

На всякий случай приложу свои потуги в решение проблемы

```
'''

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
using namespace  std;
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    ifstream fin("inputcpp.txt");
    ofstream fout("outputcpp.txt");
    list <string> grades;
    string str;
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        getline(fin, grades[i]);
        i++;
    }
    cout << grades;
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}

'''
```

Решение задачи на Python:

[image: Решение задачи на Python]

Comment: код — кодом ...

Comment: Считать число из файла можно также как и с клавиатуры.

Comment: так конкретно что именно вы не понимаете?

Comment: Грубо говоря, как написать то же самое на C++

Comment: Может это прозвучит грубо, но: руками...

Comment: Справедливо, конечно, но я пробовал

Comment: В python я содержимое файла записываю в строку через split(' '), а затем заполняю массив. В C++ таким образом, видимо, поступить нельзя и я ищу альтернативу

Comment: Читайте сразу числа, а не строку.

Comment: Но как? Не вот так ведь:
       _list <int> grades;
 fin >> grades;
 cout << grades;_

Comment: Можно в одну строку: `copy(istream_iterator<int>(fin), istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter(grades));` Это для `list<int> grades;`

Comment: Чтоб заполнить список сразу без двоек можно написать так: `copy_if(istream_iterator<int>(fin), istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter(grades), [](const int& val){return val != 2;});`

Comment: Простите, что туплю на ровном месте, просто действительно почти не работал с c++. Я записал `copy(istream_iterator<int>(fin), istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter(grades));` , но при попытке вывести полученный grades ловлю ошибку:
_No match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘const std::list_int’)_ 
Что делать?